# jQuery floating menu - show after scrollbar reaches 1280 px

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I want to use this [floating menu](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery-floating-menu.html) but only want the menu to appear after the user scrollbar is at 1280px. Dynamic drive has a [good example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/scrolltop.htm). Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the js call:

```
//config
$float_speed=1500; //milliseconds
$float_easing="easeOutQuint";
$menu_fade_speed=500; //milliseconds
$closed_menu_opacity=0.75;

//cache vars
$fl_menu=$("#fl_menu");
$fl_menu_menu=$("#fl_menu .menu");
$fl_menu_label=$("#fl_menu .label");

$(window).load(function() {
    menuPosition=$('#fl_menu').position().top;
    FloatMenu();
    $fl_menu.hover(
        function(){ //mouse over
            $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, 1);
            $fl_menu_menu.fadeIn($menu_fade_speed);
        },
        function(){ //mouse out
            $fl_menu_label.fadeTo($menu_fade_speed, $closed_menu_opacity);
            $fl_menu_menu.fadeOut($menu_fade_speed);
        }
    );
});

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    FloatMenu();
});

function FloatMenu(){
    var scrollAmount=$(document).scrollTop();
    var newPosition=menuPosition+scrollAmount;
    if($(window).height()<$fl_menu.height()+$fl_menu_menu.height()){
        $fl_menu.css("top",menuPosition);
    } else {
        $fl_menu.stop().animate({top: newPosition}, $float_speed, $float_easing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good use case to employ [jQuery Waypoints Plugin](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) which has amazing functionality that does not only what you're trying to do, but more, including custom analytics and "sticky" headers/footers

Comment: This is a great plugin - just used it after reading this thread and it  very quickly can produce the effect requested above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, just add this line in the `FloatMenu()` function:

```
$fl_menu.css('display', scrollAmount<1280? 'none' : 'block');
```

Obviously, this has to go *after* you define scrollAmount.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin for jQuery does something similar, it allows you to trigger an event when the browser scrolls to a particular element. Not exactly what you asked for, but very related and helpful:

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/